# Where is all the new content for the photo site?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

So I’ve been addicted to the whole stack exchange site for a couple of days. Didn’t know there are 177 sites but they are all the same as far as reputation voting etc.

Photos was the first site I came to that I needed a answer and got it twice.

Question is why isn’t there more content here? I’m looking under top questions, hot, week and nothing it’s like every 5 hours or so something new comes up.

What’s going on?

Yes I know that you can browse by tags to find new things but what else is there?

Is this even the right place to ask this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this even the right place to ask this?

Sure, here is fine. [Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14/photography-chat) is also a good place to ask this sort of thing. Not that there's a lot of activity there. Or here at Meta, for that matter.

> Question is why isn’t there more content here? I’m looking under top questions, hot, week and nothing it’s like every 5 hours or so something new comes up.
>
> What’s going on?

Well, we do have a *lot* of content here. But we also have a lot of questions that are repeatedly asked (how to mount lens X with camera body Y, can I use made-for-Nikon wireless trigger with a Canon, how do I use feature Z on my camera (but I haven't read the manual), etc.), which often get closed as duplicates. We also get a lot of questions that are just off-topic (especially shopping-related questions), so we try to closed those swiftly.

Over the last few years, this site has experienced declining participation by long-term regulars. Partly, it's a natural part of every site's life cycle, it seems. But for PSE in particular, it seems we have declining participation in general. Don't know what else to say. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Even the Photo of the Week competitions have been a bit lackluster lately, but I believe that is mostly due to a run of uninspiring themes. Unfortunately, we don't have high enough numbers to run statistically meaningful stats.

Comment: Thanks, it seems like when you first come here to ask the question you wait a day then you get an answer or some comments. From people with a lot of reputation. Then once it’s answered your like I might have another question but you don’t wanna ask cause it might get downvoted or put as a duplicate. And as a new user your like what does this even mean. You don’t find out until you stay here for a couple of days and go to like meta.stackexchange and read the faq and all the rules and then your like oh so that’s how this place works. It’s not instant like Reddit. I’ll stop ranting. Thanks 

Comment: @Jcb No, definitely not like Reddit or any other internet forum, etc., that's for sure.